# show restaurants within 100 miles

Tags: php, mysql

I have a master zip code table `tbl_zipcode` with all latitude and longitude values. Also a restaurant table with restaurant list with zip codes.

Now I want to show the restaurants within 100 miles from user location i.e. from session user. How can I write a function which returns all the restaurants within 100 miles?

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show us that you tried something to solve your problem. Otherwise it looks like you're too lazy to solve your issues.

Comment: This question is too open ended.  Are you asking about how to architect such a system?  How to paginate results (100 mile radius can have thousands of restaurants)?  Or do you just need algorithms for lat/lon?  If the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652167/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-of-latitude-and-longitude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance within 100 miles in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036909/calculate-distance-within-100-miles-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you have the longitude and latitude of the user and of all the restaurants..

check haversine formula
this is helpful: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

To implement the formula is pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

Determine all of the ZIP codes in a 100 mile radius from where you want to start (which is the current ZIP code based on the position of the session user), and include all Restaurants with those ZIP codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to device a way to calculate the distance between the user to those zip code's lat long.

Source: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to get the lat/long values of the current user's zip code.

```
SELECT latitude,longitude FROM tbl_zipcode WHERE zipcode = <USER_ZIPCODE>
```

Then you can use those values to calculate the distance for each coordinates pair in the database, e.g. by using this [script](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.php.html) (written in PHP so no time wasted thinking about Java functions).

But you might want to think about caching since it's a pretty heavy operation to do for each coordinates pair. Maybe you can precalculate those values and update the database each time a new restaurant comes in or so.

Comment: Thanks. But it only gives the distance of restaurants, I want all the restaurants within that 100 miles. How can I make a function which returns all the restaurants within 100 miles?

Comment: Please think about your problem first instead of asking immediately. Most problems were solved by using brain cells and no one is here to solve it but to help you solve it. Possible solution: Given the current set of zip codes within the 100 miles range of the user, you select every restaurant that has a zip code that belongs to that set.