# How to calculate distance to locations

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've developed an iPhone application to parse data from an XML file. This data contains a set of longitudes and latitudes for different places.

How do I detect nearest of them according to my current location on the map and how do I set set a range to show places in this range?

Comment: You can use the `distanceFromLocation:` method, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3905896/154803)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905896/distancefromlocation-calculate-distance-between-two-points, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652167/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-of-latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 1):

```
CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:myLatitude longitude:myLongitude];

CLLocation *myXmlLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:xmlLatitude longitude:xmlLongitude];

CLLocationDistance distance = [myLocation distanceFromLocation: myXmlLocation];
```

This is in meters, so you must do any converting from there. They are also linear, so these aren't driving direction lengths by any means.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

some trig, but really not too difficult.

this page has an example script, not in your language, but it contains explainations and the equations you need.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

and also, please don't write run-on sentences, it took me a while to read your question.

Answer (score 0):

@Vinnie said is absolutely right but these values is air distance.

Also this method is deprecated in iOS 3.2

```
- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(const CLLocation *)location Parameters
```

You can't find the distance based on roads with the Apple SDK. Try to use [google APIs](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/index.html) for finding distance between two points on earth on roads.